# Uima Ruta CW Annotation

Tags: uima, ruta

I'm using Uima Ruta 2.5.0 Version. In this, Symbols like Γ,Δ were coming under CW .Why its Happening?

Input
Γ
Δ

Answer (score 1):

The CW annotation like the other TokenSeed annotations is created by a JFlex lexer. The rule for CW is `[:uppercase:][:lowercase:]*` whereas `[:uppercase:]`  is defined by the Unicode properties `\p{Uppercase}`. Both of your example symbols are greek uppercase letters.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*